# What is wrong with this insert query for Aurora postgres 10.7?

Tags: postgresql

I'm stumped as to why I'm getting the following error

> operator does not exist: character varying = text[]

when the following query is running in production:-

```
INSERT INTO message_status 
  (created_datetime,correlation_id,batch_id,entity_type,entity_id,entity_status,entity_message,effective_date) 
VALUES 
  ('2020-02-04 10:24:14.291000000','6dc16864-5820-475e-918e-51b15722c08a','34d9c646-9bc2-4389-9789-9c0482ba743e','Benchmark','ABCDEFGH','VALIDATION_ERRORED','{"type":"NO_RESULTS","properties":{}}','2020-01-12');
```

Not able to reproduce LOCALLY or in DBEAVER. Is there anything obviously wrong with this query? We recently migrated from AWS RDS MySQL to AWS Aurora Postgres

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE public.message_status (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    correlation_id varchar(36) NULL,
    entity_type varchar(32) NULL,
    entity_id varchar(32) NULL,
    entity_status varchar(32) NULL,
    entity_message text NULL,
    effective_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    record_count int4 NULL,
    created_datetime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    batch_id varchar(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT message_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
CREATE INDEX ix_message_status ON public.message_status USING btree (effective_date, entity_type, entity_id, created_datetime) ;
CREATE INDEX ix_message_status_effective_date ON public.message_status USING btree (effective_date) ;
```

Postgres version = 10.7
pg-promise npm library version = 9.2.1

Comment: The error message can't come (directly) from that statement. Do you have any triggers on that table? Btw: UUIDs are better stored in a column defined as `uuid`, not in `varchar` columns

Comment: There are no triggers on the table. There are the following indexes:- 

CREATE INDEX ix_message_status ON public.message_status USING btree (effective_date, entity_type, entity_id, created_datetime)
CREATE INDEX ix_message_status_effective_date ON public.message_status USING btree (effective_date)

Comment: You cannot store an array[] into a column scalar defined column (text). Thus '{"type":"NO_RESULTS","properties":{}}' cannot be inserted into the column entity_message. To be specific the error message says Postgres cannot find a conversion function to convert an array to text. Try changing to error_message text[]; unless of course there are other places just inserting simple text into it.

Comment: @Belayer there are other places inserting text and surely this should just be inserted as a raw string anyway as per the above insert?